# Limit of double sum

Tags: analysis

I need to evaluate the following limit of double sum
$$
   \lim\limits_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{m=1}^{N-1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{N-m}\frac{(t-\tau)^k}{k!}
$$
but got no idea on how to proceed, any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{N-1} \sum_{k=1}^m \bigg(-\frac1n\bigg)^{N-m} \frac{(t-\tau)^k}{k!} &= \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{(t-\tau)^k}{k!} \sum_{m=k}^{N-1} \bigg(-\frac1n\bigg)^{N-m} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \frac{(t-\tau)^k}{k!} \sum_{j=1}^{N-k} \bigg(-\frac1n\bigg)^j.
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{N-1} \sum_{k=1}^m \bigg(-\frac1n\bigg)^{N-m} \frac{(t-\tau)^k}{k!} &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(t-\tau)^k}{k!} \sum_{j=1}^\infty \bigg(-\frac1n\bigg)^j \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(t-\tau)^k}{k!} \bigg( {-}\frac1{n+1} \bigg) \\
&= {-}\frac1{n+1} \big( e^{t-\tau}-1 \big).
\end{align*}